# Stuck on "Loading...Welcome to GRUB!" when trying to install Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: boot, live-usb, usb-installation, 20.10

A few minutes after turning on, PC gets stuck on either

`Loading...`
`Welcome to GRUB!` {if flash drive is written in ISO Image mode}

or

`GRUB` {if flash drive is written in DD Image mode}

when installing official Ubuntu 20.10 from a bootable flash drive(32 GB) made using Rufus 3.12.

Laptop is HP Pavilion dv6 Notebook PC(Intel Core i7) with BIOS (Version F.1C) and without UEFI. It got 2 graphics cards (that switch automatically depending on requirements).

I am currently dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu DDE 20.04 - both of which are working fine.

Comment: Hey Muhammad Anas Qasmi! Are you trying to install Ubuntu DDE 20.10 or Canonical's official Ubuntu 20.10?

Comment: @technastic_tc "Official" - I added this word in the question. Ubuntu DDE 20.10 is not available(20.04 works fine).

Comment: Actually DDE is off-topic in Ask Ubuntu. That's the reason why I asked. But official Ubuntu flavours are on-topic. So are you trying to remove any one of your OSs or triple boot?

Comment: In this case it might be prudent to attach a picture of what you're seeing.  If it's dropping you to a grub prompt then it's likely the ISOs aren't written properly.  (Also, DDE 20.04 is offtopic as is DDE 20.10 so keep that in mind going forward)

Comment: @Thomas Ward I am not talking about installing DDE - just mentioned it is working fine currently. The picture I see is just those lines I mentioned on top of a black screen - nothing else. I have tried making bootable drive with the Ubuntu ISO multiple times. I am trying to remove DDE 20.04 and replace it with Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: @technastic_tc Oh thanks a lot for that link :) I will try that until this problem gets fixed.

Comment: @MuhammadAnasQasmi Do add a photo for reference. It'll be helpful.